# Conjugacy class size and simple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$, it is denoted by $N(G)$ the set of conjugacy class sizes. Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ be a finite non-abelian simple group. Is it possible that $N(G)=N(H)$? In fact, I guess that $G$ should be simple but I cannot prove it. Can you help me?

Comment: We could have $G = H \times A$ for any abelian group $A$. Perhaps you want $N(G)$ to be the multiset of conjugacy class sizes rather than just the set?

Comment: sorry, but I cannot understand your mean. In my question $G$ and $H$ are two distinct group. $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$. How you can write $G=H\times A$?

Comment: Why should I not write $G = H \times A$ if I want to? I have answered the question you asked below.

Answer (score 3):

Let $H = A_5$, the finite simple group of order $60$. Let $G = A_5 \times C_2$ the direct product of $A_5$ with a cyclic group of order $2$. Then the set of conjugacy class sizes of $H$, i.e. $N(H)$ is equal to $\{1,12,15,20\}$. The set $N(G)$ of conjugacy class sizes of $G$ is also equal to $\{1,12,15,20\}$. So $N(G)=N(H)$, and the answer to your question is yes, it is possible to have $N(G)=N(H)$ without $G$ being simple.